# Android app issue, during parsing XML

Tags: android, xml-parsing, dbpedia

I am trying to parse XML containing a description tag to extract just the content (summary) from it. The activity closes/stops working unexpectedly.
You can visit the link in the URL and add your query to see the XML result I'm trying to parse.

```java
public class ResultActivity extends Activity{ //implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
 InputStream is = null;
 private TextView textView;
 XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
 private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "HttpExample";
 String query,result;
 //private TextToSpeech tts;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,        //Code for full screen activity
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    query = i.getStringExtra("query");
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    myClickHandler();
    //speakout();

}

public void myClickHandler() {
        query.replace(' ', '_');
        String stringUrl = "http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryClass=place&QueryString="+query;
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);
        } else {
            textView.setText("No network connection available.");
        }
        }



/*NEW subCLASS*/
class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String ns=null;
    @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }

private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
          try {
                URL url = new URL(myurl);
                HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                // Starts the query
                conn.connect();
                int response = conn.getResponseCode();
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
                is = conn.getInputStream();

               pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
                parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                parser.setInput(is, null);
               // result=convertStreamToString(is);
                result=parseXML(parser);
              }
               catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }    finally {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                } 
            }
            return result;
        }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.


     @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView.setText(result);
     }
//FINAL TEXT VIEW WIDGET DISPLAY


private String parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        String res = null;
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();

         while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
             String name = parser.getName();
             if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
              System.out.println("Start document");
              textView.setText("Reached");
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
              System.out.println("End document");
          }
          else if(name.equals("description")) {
              res=readSummary(parser);
          } 
          eventType = parser.next();
         }
    return res;
    }

    //PARSE OUT THE DESCRIPTION TAG     

private String readSummary(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "description");
        String summary = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "description");
        return summary;
    }     

    //PARSE OUT THE DESCRIPTION CONTENT FROM THE TAG    

private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
                String result = "";
                if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    result = parser.getText();
                    parser.nextTag();
                }
                return result;

    }       

}


}
```

MY LOGCAT

```
06-19 19:47:08.344: E/Trace(662): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-19 19:47:09.666: D/gralloc_goldfish(662): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-19 19:49:32.676: D/HttpExample(662): The response is: 200
06-19 19:49:36.036: D/dalvikvm(662): GC_CONCURRENT freed 248K, 3% free 10985K/11271K, paused 79ms+40ms, total 289ms
06-19 19:53:21.125: D/gralloc_goldfish(716): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-19 19:53:53.435: D/HttpExample(716): The response is: 200
06-19 19:53:53.465: I/System.out(716): Start document
06-19 19:53:53.475: W/dalvikvm(716): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:835)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:292)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6309)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at     android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3547)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at com.example.verch.ResultActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.parseXML(ResultActivity.java:150)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at com.example.verch.ResultActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.downloadUrl(ResultActivity.java:122)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at com.example.verch.ResultActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.doInBackground(ResultActivity.java:96)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at com.example.verch.ResultActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.doInBackground(ResultActivity.java:1)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-19 19:53:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(716):  ... 5 more
06-19 19:53:57.464: I/Process(716): Sending signal. PID: 716 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The networking part is working fine. I am able to get the XML but not able to parse it.

Comment: try printing out the stream you get to a file (preferred) or to logcat and post a sample of it here. It is probably due to namespace issues (had some myself last week) and those are rather easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "description");
String summary = parser.nextText();
parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "description");
```

Comment: Where should I put this code, instead of what?
I tried putting this instead of parseXML(parser); and removing all other methods but in vain.

Comment: the differences between my code and your code is just at parser.nextText()
suppose to the parser is at START_TAG, then just use nextText() function to get the text of it. 
in your code, you're using parser.getText() to get the text but i'm afraid it never reach that, did you trace it already until then ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a parsing error.
As the exception says you cannot handle views inside a thread unless it is the UI thread.
In the parseXML, which runs on the background thread, you try to setText on a view.